# Create table never ending

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I try to create table in my Postgres database. I use pgadmin in version 1.18.1. Postgres version on server is 8.3.12.

When I execute create table statement, usually it done in few ms, but sometimes it go on few minutes and I stopping it. Then I have to restart the Postgres server, which is undesirable. I tried create table before people come to work, but that didn't work too.

Has someone similar problem? How can I fix that?
Restart server is sometimes really problematic.

Comment: It's probably waiting for a lock: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring But why are you using an ancient and unsupported Postgres version?

Comment: It doesn't depend on me... Our managment doesn't allow to update. We have little war when we wanted update Java from version 6 to 8...

Comment: Do you have autovacuum running? (vacuum was not run automatically before pg-8.4, IIRC)

Comment: @wildplasser we don't have autovacuum on. Our IT department do vacuum manually every Sunday.

Comment: Well,there is nothing you can do. Upgrade to at least 9.x. And upgrade the IT-department to some level of competence, too.

Comment: yep. we are working on upgrade postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some GUI database administration programs with Postgres support start in noautocommit mode by default. This means that if you don't commit your statements implicitly this programs would maintain idle uncommitted sessions for long time, locking resources — especially when you do DDL statements like `create table`.

Check:

```
select now()-query_start as query_age, *
from pg_stat_activity 
where state<>'idle'
order by 1 desc;
```

if you see lines with long times in `query_age` column and in `idle in transaction` state then you really need to enable autocommit in your client program. Actually you need to do this even if you don't…

Comment: thanks for answer, Postgres 8.3 don't have 'state' column. There is only 'current_query' column where can be `<IDLE> in transaction`